# Getting a USB remote controller to work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, drivers, udev

I'm at a lost at setting up a USB remote controller on Ubuntu Natty with Kernel 2.6.38-12-generic. It's a "USB pen" used to control the routine of Slideshows (Powerpoint, ... , etc)
It recognizes the device fine, with the following dmesg message:

> [333503.528090] input: HID-compliant Mouse HID-compliant Mouse as
> /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/input/input22
>
> [333503.528231] generic-usb 0003:1D57:AC01.000B: input,hidraw1: USB
> HID v1.10 Keyboard [HID-compliant Mouse HID-compliant Mouse] on
> usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.3/input0

and with xinput a new device is found:

> ⎣ Virtual core keyboard
>
> ```
> ↳ HID-compliant Mouse HID-compliant Mouse     id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
> ```

but "*xinput test*" wont get any events.

with *lsusb* I can see:
Bus 002 Device 085: ID 1d57:ac01

And it works fine in Oracle VirtualBox within which an XP machine is set up. So I think it's not so much of a device problem but rather how to configure it to work as a remote controller. (I noticed that on some descriptions it's marked as keyboard and others mouse)

Any suggestions or experience would be appreciated.

-----------------------Detailed description from xinput--------------------

```
Bus 002 Device 085: ID 1d57:ac01  
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x1d57 
  idProduct          0xac01 
  bcdDevice           11.10
  iManufacturer           1 HID-compliant Mouse
  iProduct                2 HID-compliant Mouse
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           34
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.10
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      78
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               8
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

Comment: with : /lib/udev/findkeyboards i can see it too
USB keyboard: input/event6

Comment: Are events reported using `xev`? What output do you get with `udevadm monitor --property`?